# Spring boot datasource implementation

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I am implementing a library using Spring boot framework. The library offers custom starters for Kafka, Datasource etc for the consumers. They should use the library to develop microservices.

I am facing issues in implementing the datasource autoconfiguration.

**Requirements**
The library must implement a datasource autoconfiguration which should provide the developers to use upto 2 different datasources configured in `application.yml`. This is what I have done so far.

```
library/
      |__autoconfigure/
                      |__datasource/
                                   |__DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java
                                   |__PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration.java
                                   |__SecondaryDataSourceConfiguration.java
      |__datasource/
                   |__CustomRepository.java
      |
      |__datasource-spring-boot-starter/
```

**Code**

**DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean({DataSource.class})
@ConditionalOnClass({JpaRepository.class})
public class DataSourceAutoConfiguration {

}
```

**PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    )
public class PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
        entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
        ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
        entityManagerFactory
        ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
service: 
  datasource: 
    hikari:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test 
      username: root
      password: root
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When the service starts, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1063) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: where `application.yml` located? are you sure it was loaded? should be in `src/main/java/resources`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jdbcUrl](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/) property (especially for Spring Boot and MySQL):

```
service:
  datasource: 
    hikari:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

> Note: Spring Boot auto-configuration users, you need to use jdbcUrl-based configuration.
>
> The MySQL DataSource is known to be broken with respect to network timeout support. Use jdbcUrl configuration instead.

Comment: I get the same error even after using this property

Comment: @cppcoder add `service` level before `datasource` in yaml

Comment: It does not help

Comment: Try adding url in level:spring.service.datasource.url

Comment: Tried that with no luck. Looks like problem is not with the properties.